# PayPal Popup Disappears on Checkout

Tags: paypal

I'm about to create a PayPal payment gateway for donations on my website, it goes fine with the sandbox account, but when I turn to the live mode, it does not end well.
The PayPal check-out window pop and disappear immediately in a live mode before even showing anything in that window. The only thing I changed on the live mode is the post URL which I replaced "api-m.sandbox." with "api-m." behind this "paypal.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing I changed on the live mode is the post URL which I replaced "api-m.sandbox." with "api-m." behind this "paypal.com"

You also need to use a live client id an secret from the developer dashboard [Apps and Credentials](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications), and the JS SDK must have the same live client id for its `src` when loaded.

---

As an aside (since this is for donations) consider the simpler [donate SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/donate/donate-sdk/) which does not use API calls, and offers a payment experience more tailored for this.

If you do stick with the main JS SDK for some reason, `style: { label: "donate" }` can be used in the button initialization to add that text to the button, if desired.

```
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: { label: "donate" },
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a champion. I did not use the live client id on the JS SDK.